# git: how to remove all commits with a pattern?

Tags: git, github, version-control

We use git for source control. Each time there is a commit from developers, a script would modify a build file and checks in the file. The script commits the build file with a message that follows a pattern. So the commit history is like the following:

- script checkin build file 003
- fix this bug
- script checkin build file 002
- resolve that story

What I want to do is to remove all commits by the script. Now, obviously, this is very different from removing a particular commit.

I have the freedom to start a brand new repository by copying from existing repository, but I still want to preserve the "developer's commit history" as much as possible, while getting rid of the "script's commit history".

Is that possible?

Note - the "script's commits" only changed this single file (that is, the build file), and did not change any other file. And, no "developer's commit" ever changed this particular file.

So far what I have been doing is to run "bfg tool" to delete that particular build file from the git repo. Only the commits from the script ever changed the build file, so I am hoping by removing the build file, the associated commits would be squashed away by git.

But, what I found is: the build file is gone, yet all commits are preserved, and those commits, curiously, having "0 changes".

So my next question is: is it possible to ask git to remove commits with "0 changes"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git filter-branch`. An easy way to do it is if your script has a unique Author Name. Then you can do something like:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Script Person" ];
    then
        skip_commit "$@";
    else
        git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

This is pretty much right out of the man page. There are a few different variables you can check against if there's something else that uniquely identifies your script as the committer.

Comment: man page has "NOTE the changes introduced by the commits, and which are not reverted by subsequent commits, will still be in the rewritten branch. If you want to throw out changes together with the commits, you should use the interactive mode of git rebase.", so maybe the rebase approach is the way to go?

Comment: Hi @DavidNeiss, he mentions that the commits now have zero changes as he's already removed the file, so not an issue in this case. However, in the case you also want to remove changes, rebase is definitely your friend.

Answer (score 0):

[**Squash your commits**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages)

Recently, I faced the same problem, I had 41 commits on my pull requests. I will only touch something what I have implemented.

For instance, if you have 3 commits, you can squash them and make into one using interactive rebase. See below command:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

For example, you want to squash 3 commits:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Now, you see an interactive rebase interface, where you can write reword/pick on first commit and squash on rest of them. Please see this video for better understanding.

[Squashing commits video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IfkL8swmFw)

> This is easy, will not take longer. I worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, git filter-branch has an option to prune commits which end up being empty. Check its manpage for exact name.